# Dynamic Linking/Referencing of Classes at Runtime on Android

Tags: java, android, runtime, apk, subclassing

I am wondering is there is a simple and clean way of achieving the desired functionality below:

I have a main APK that provides the core functionality of my application, which contains an abstract class to be extended. There are various other APKs, each containing a unique subclass of the abstract class and overriding some of its methods in order to provided extended functionality. When these subclasses are instantiated, they require decoding of resources contained in their respective APKs. I chose to have these subclasses in separate APKs to allow the user to install only the desired components without having to modify the main APK, which will provide a list of all available components on launch.

My main questions:

Is there a way to reference a class in another APK without duplicating code like my subclasses are trying to accomplish?
Is it possible to reference or pass the instantiated subclasses back to my main application where the overridden methods will be called with only knowledge of the original abstract class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the APKs are signed with the same certificate, you can use the method outlined in this answer:

[Android: how to share code between projects signed with the same certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721386/android-how-to-share-code-between-projects-signed-with-the-same-certificate)