# How can I call a method of one apk from another apk in android

Tags: android, apk

I have a requirement where there is a first apk say APK1. From here I want to call a method of second apk, means APK2. Is it possible to do this? If so kindly help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the APKs are signed with the same certificate, you can use the method outlined in this answer:

[Android: how to share code between projects signed with the same certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721386/android-how-to-share-code-between-projects-signed-with-the-same-certificate)

Comment: I think these links are not much throwing light on the code base set up... Any links for the implemented application on these lines??

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are asking, but it might be what you really want. If you have two applications and wish to communicate between them (run second app's Activity from the first one), use `Intent`s. This is what they are for.